# Image.asset not showing assets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried restarting, flutter doctor, flutter pub upgrade.

```
══════════════╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞══════════════
    
    The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
    Unable to load asset: "Sun, Sep 10, 2023 - 11:39 PM".
    Exception: Asset not found
    
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    #0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:295:7)
    #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:731:35)
    #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:695:14)
    #3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:513:13)     
    #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:384:22)
    #5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:511:81)
    #6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:106:19)  
    #7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:358:9)
    #8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure>
    (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:473:24)
    #9      SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41:39)
    #10     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:470:9)
    #11     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:355:5)
    #12     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1119:16)
    #13     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1069:5)
    #14     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5119:11)
    #15     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4944:5)
    ...     Normal element mounting (15 frames)
    #30     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3953:16)
    #31     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3682:18)
    #32     SlottedRenderObjectElement._updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/slotted_render_object_widget.dart:270:33)   
    #33     SlottedRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/slotted_render_object_widget.dart:224:5)
    ...     Normal element mounting (192 frames)
    #225    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3953:16)
    #226    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3682:18)
    #227    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1451:37)
    #228    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1436:20)      
    #229    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2682:19)
    #230    SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1428:12)
    #231    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure>
    (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:353:23)
    #232    RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2300:59)
    #233    PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1056:15)
    #234    RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2300:14)
    #235    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:342:5)#236    RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.addInitialChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:428:5)     
    #237    RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:79:12)
    #238    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #239    RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:149:12)
    #240    RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:386:11)
    #241    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #242    RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:550:13)
    #243    RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1994:12)
    #244    RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1939:20)
    #245    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #246    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #247    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #248    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #249    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #250    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #251    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #252    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #253    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #254    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #255    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #256    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #257    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #258    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #259    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #260    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #261    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #262    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #263    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #264    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #265    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #266    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #267    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #268    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #269    RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:552:11)
    #270    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #271    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #272    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #273    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #274    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #275    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
    #276    RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:836:43)
    #277    RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:938:32)
    #278    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #279    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #280    RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:240:12)
    #281    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #282    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #283    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
    #284    RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:903:45)
    #285    RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:938:32)
    #286    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #287    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #288    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
    #289    RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:836:43)
    #290    RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:938:32)
    #291    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #292    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #293    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
    #294    RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:836:43)
    #295    RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:938:32)
    #296    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #297    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #298    _RenderSingleChildViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/single_child_scroll_view.dart:502:14)
    #299    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #300    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #301    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #302    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #303    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #304    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #305    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #306    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #307    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #308    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #309    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #310    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #311    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #312    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #313    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #314    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #315    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #316    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #317    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #318    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #319    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #320    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #321    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #322    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #323    RenderCustomPaint.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:552:11)
    #324    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #325    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #326    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #327    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #328    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #329    ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:56:11)
    #330    RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:595:43)
    #331    RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:622:12)
    #332    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #333    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #334    MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
    #335    _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1080:7)
    #336    MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
    #337    RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:410:14)
    #338    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #339    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #340    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #341    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #342    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #343    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #344    _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1467:11)
    #345    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #346    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #347    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #348    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #349    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #350    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #351    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #352    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #353    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #354    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #355    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #356    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #357    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #358    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #359    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #360    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #361    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #362    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #363    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #364    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #365    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #366    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #367    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #368    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #369    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #370    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #371    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #372    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #373    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #374    RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3813:14)
    #375    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #376    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #377    RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:120:14)
    #378    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2189:7)
    #379    RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2430:11)
    #380    _RenderTheatre.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:856:15)
    #381    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2027:7)
    #382    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1020:18)
    #383    RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:516:19)
    #384    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:865:13)
    #385    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:381:5)
    #386    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1289:15)
    #387    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1218:9)
    #388    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1076:5)
    #389    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:13)
    #390    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:338:5)
    #391    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
    
    Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "Sun, Sep 10, 2023 - 11:39 PM")
    Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#591f7(), name: "Sun, Sep 10, 2023 - 11:39
      PM", scale: 1.0)
    ══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: "Shawarma".
```

This is the widget code:

```
Widget _buildNewCategory(String title, List<NotifPageItem> notifications) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        title,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 26,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.red.shade100,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Expanded(child: Divider()),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: const Text('Mark as read'),
                          onTap: () {
                            if (newNotifications.isNotEmpty &&
                                thisWeekNotifications.isEmpty) {
                              thisWeekNotifications = [...newNotifications];
                              newNotifications.clear();
                              setState(() {});
                            } else {
                              for (int i = 0;
                                  i < newNotifications.length;
                                  i++) {
                                thisWeekNotifications.add(newNotifications[i]);
                              }
                              newNotifications.clear();
                              setState(() {});
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(),
                ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: notifications.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    int reverseIndex = notifications.length - 1 - index;
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 100,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red.shade300),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Image.asset(
                                  notifications[reverseIndex].imgUrl),
                              title: Text(
                                notifications[reverseIndex].noOfItems == 1
                                    ? '${notifications[reverseIndex].notifTitle}\n${notifications[reverseIndex].orderState}\nYou ordered ${notifications[reverseIndex].foodTitle}'
                                    : '${notifications[reverseIndex].notifTitle}\n${notifications[reverseIndex].orderState}\nYou ordered ${notifications[reverseIndex].foodTitle} + ${notifications[reverseIndex].noOfItems - 1}',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                ),
                              ),
                              trailing: notifications[reverseIndex].noOfItems ==
                                      1
                                  ? Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Image.asset(
                                          notifications[reverseIndex].varImgUrl,
                                          height: 35,
                                          width: 35,
                                        ),
                                        Image.asset(
                                          notifications[reverseIndex].imgUrl, //
                                          height: 95,
                                          width: 91,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  : Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        Positioned(
                                          right: 10,
                                          bottom: 6,
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                            notifications[reverseIndex].imgUrl,
                                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                            height: 50,
                                            width: 50,
                                            colorBlendMode: BlendMode.lighten,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Image.asset(
                                          notifications[reverseIndex].imgUrl,
                                          height: 95,
                                          width: 91,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                notifications[reverseIndex].time,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

ff

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2846], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

EDIT: I made changes to the notification page item class the previous night, woke up the next morning and forgot I did. I was then passing the wrong arguments to the class. Like passing `title` where I should have passed the `imageUrl`.

Comment: where did you get notifications.length? is that coming from API or local json?

Comment: `notifications` is a list containing instances of a NotifPageItem class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that the problem is about your data because you're searching the image: "Sun, Sep 10, 2023 - 11:39 PM" and this doesnt look like an image (I think that your image can look like `assets/imgs/Sun, Sep 10, 2023 - 11:39 PM.jpg`), you need to be sure that you have this local image exactly as you have been registered on your pubspect.yaml

Other possible error can be the way as you declare the assets on your pubspect.yaml, if you want to load an entire folder you need to declare the path of your images folder with a "/" in the end

```
  assets:
    - assets/img/
```

Comment: OMGGG. I was providing the wrong arguments to the instance. Brooo I thought I was going crazy. It all makes sense now. Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're providing the wrong asset name to your `Image.asset` widget. You're providing the timestamp `Sun, Sep 10, 2023 - 11:39 PM` as an `asset path` in the image widget, which is incorrect. So, it means your code is searching for a timestamp in the `assets folder`.

Comment: Yesssss. Turns out I was giving the wrong arguments to the class instance. Thanks for the help